# How can I repeat random walker simulation?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, random

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

def randomwalk():
  n=1000
  x=np.zeros(n)
  y=np.zeros(n)
  for i in range (1,n):
    theta=2.0*np.pi*np.random.rand()
    x[i] = x[i-1] + math.cos(theta)
    y[i] = y[i-1] + math.sin(theta)
 return x, y
```

Above line is just for one operation and works fine.
I modified this like below to make a loop and to find the average distance.

```
def randomwalk():
  n=1000
 
  x=np.zeros(n)
  y=np.zeros(n)
  for i in range (1,n):
    theta=2.0*np.pi*np.random.rand()
    x[i] = x[i-1] + math.cos(theta)
    y[i] = y[i-1] + math.sin(theta)
 return x, y

sum=0
num=20
for z in range(num):
  randomwalk()
  distance=math.sqrt(x[n-1]**2+y[n-1]**2)
  sum+=distance
average=sum/num
print(average)
```

How can I fix this? I'm a beginner
I have no idea how I should use variable when I repeat something
And also how can I plot 20 random walker operations together in one graph?

```
def plotrandomwalk():
  randomwalk()
  x_data, y_data = randomwalk()
  plt.title("Random Walk")
  plt.plot(x_data, y_data)
  plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please add more details about what's not working with the code you have written? Also, do you wish to animate a random walk something like [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/random_walk.html#sphx-glr-gallery-animation-random-walk-py) but in 2D?

Comment: `randomwalk()` returns a pair of numpy arrays but you don't save these values in any of your code except this line: `x_data, y_data = randomwalk()`. All you calls to `randomwalk()` should look something like that. Also, don't use `sum` as a variable name as it hides the built-in function of that same name in that scope.

Comment: Step one: always, _always_, **always** seed your random number generator. After which step two is to just generate a random seed if you need a random run, and then use that same seed value to run the code a second time in the exact same way. If you don't _need_ `np.random.rand()` (i.e. you didn't write a full page justification for np.random over any other PRNG) then just use Python's built in [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html), which is trivially seeded.

Comment: Can you guys explain a little more about how I can find the average distance? I don’t understand..